# Flash navigateToURL hangs after navigation starts?

Tags: flash, flash-builder, navigatetourl

I have a flash program in a web page that tries to post a picture to a web page.  When the user clicks a button the web browser starts to navigate to the new page then seems to hang (I can see it starts to go to the page by reading the transferring data from message in Firefox status bar)

This also seems to work in debug version but not the exported version.

Flash code:

```
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://myurl.com/webcam_upload.php");

jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
jpgURLRequest.data = encodedData;

try
{
    navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "_Self");
}
catch(e:Error)
{
    trace("error occured");
}
```

Web page:

```
<object width='534' height='450' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='flash/photobooth.swf'>
<param name='allowNetworking' value='all'>
<param name='allowScriptAccess' value='always'>
<param name='movie' value='flash/photobooth.swf'>       
<p>My stuff.</p>
</object>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to "navigate to a url" so navigateToURL is not what you want here. What you want to do is to call a url using URLLoader, along with a header and the encoded image...

```
// First create your URL variables — your encodedData
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.image = encodedData;

// Secondly you need to create a URLRequest, passing the URLVariables and any header you want
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("http://myurl.com/webcam_upload.php");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.data = variables;

// Finally you want to create the URLLoader, calling the URLRequest and listening to any listeners you want, ie COMPLETE...
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE, _onPostReturn, false, 0, true);
loader.load (request);

private function _onPostReturn(evt:Event):void {

       // This will trace the response upon completion.
       trace ( evt.target.data );

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the browser still starts the transfering data and then just sits there without reloading the web page.

Comment: Does the trace outputs anything? The .php should return something back to flash in order for you to then redirect the web page.

Comment: No, as I undestand it trace only works in debug mode.  The flash program seems to work in debug mode but not in the 'published' release version.

Comment: It should be going to a new page just as if you had posted a html form.

Comment: I've managed to get it working :o).  It seem that the project file some how was corrupt.  Just creating a new project (with a different name) and then copying and pasting the code seems to have made it work.

Comment: i'm glad you found a solution.